# Spring Boot Servlet Filter Not Called

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlet-filters

Hello I am new to Spring Boot and I am struggling creating a filter; the filter class I have created is not invoked when the project starts or even when I am sending API requests (Is not calling init, doFilter, and destroy).
Currently I am NOT using spring boot web and I am BUILDING spring boot with gradle and running React front-end and Spring boot as back end. I have created a Filter Class where it implements Filter from `import javax.servlet.*` and uses `@Components`. Like shown below.

```
@Component
public class DeviceFilter implements Filter{
    @Autowired
    DeviceRepository deviceRepository;
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DeviceFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("INIT FILTER.....");
    }



    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("DO FILTER.....");
        LOG.info("Logging");
        System.out.println("INFO");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("DESTORY FILTER.....");
    }
}
```

Furthermore I think I am suppose to add/ map filter in web.xml but since I built the project with gradle the project doesn't have web.xml so I have created a `@Configuration` class where I have mapped the filter like shown below.

```
@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<DeviceFilter> filterRegistrationBean(){
        FilterRegistrationBean<DeviceFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new DeviceFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something or am I doing something wrong? Please Help Thank you!
PS: Also when I run spring boot from main class the console prints like shown below

```
2021-09-10 11:27:51.725  INFO 66959 --- [main] a.m.s.Project    : Starting Project using Java 16 on Bob-MBP-2 with PID 66959 (/Users/bob/Development/project/build/classes/java/main started by bob in /Users/bob/Development/project)
2021-09-10 11:27:51.727  INFO 66959 --- [main] a.m.s.Project    : The following profiles are active: dev
2021-09-10 11:27:52.422  INFO 66959 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data R2DBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-10 11:27:52.521  INFO 66959 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 96 ms. Found 16 R2DBC repository interfaces.
2021-09-10 11:27:54.725  INFO 66959 --- [main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 9020
2021-09-10 11:27:54.736  INFO 66959 --- [main] a.m.s.Project    : Started Project in 3.355 seconds (JVM running for 4.041)
```

Comment: *NOT using spring boot web* So are you running Netty in Servlet mode or not? If no, then your Filter is meaningless; if you are, you don't need any of the registration business, just put a bean into the Spring context and Boot will do it automatically.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I am using webflux so reactor netty should be configured automatically; however, even with or without the registration business the servlet filter is not invoked

Comment: Try using the `org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter` interface from the [WebHadler API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-web-handler-api)

Comment: If you aren't using Servlets, then Servlet filters won't work. Use Saleem's suggestion.

Comment: @SaleemKhair Thank you. Using WebFilter Solved the Problem

Answer (score 0):

*Try this one it it gonna work. You forgot to inject the DeviceFilter*

```
    @Configuration
public class FilterConfig {
@Autowired
DeviceFilter deviceFilter
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<DeviceFilter> filterRegistrationBean(){
        FilterRegistrationBean<DeviceFilter> registrationBean = new 
           FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(deviceFilter);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```